# Getter methods in java with asynchronous connection needing a delay

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making a series of connections asynchronously via MySQL, and I have a class which contains a bunch of easy-accesible static methods to update/remove/clear/get/etc data.

The issue I'm confronted with is that the getter methods won't return the proper value (practically ever) because they are returned before the async connection gets a chance to update the value to be returned.

Example:

```
public static int getSomething(final UUID user)
{
    Connection c = StatsMain.getInstance().getSQL().getConnection();


    PreparedStatement ps;

    try
    {
        ps = c.prepareStatement("select something from stats where uuid=?");
        ps.setString(1, user.toString());

        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        return result.getInt("something");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(Not copy & pasted, but pretty close)

I realize I can use a 'callback' effect by passing an interface to the method and doing such, but that becomes very tedious when the database stores 10 values for a key.

Comment: Why not just make it synchronous then?

Comment: Synchronous would cause the main thread to lag or freeze up, as this will be called constantly.

Comment: Good point. As far as I know then the only way to do that would be in the callback.

Comment: Dang.. It'd be neat to see some synchronous support for getter methods in java9 or something :P

Comment: Yeah, who knows, maybe someone knows something we don't...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) since Java 6 or [CompletableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), which is new in Java 8

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

The best method I've come up with is have a thread with a loop in it that waits for MySQL to return values and responds to each value.  This is rather like the callback in the get routine, but you only have the one loop.  Of course, the loop has to know what to do with each possible returned piece of data.

This means rethinking a bit how your program works.  Instead of: *ask a question, get an answer, use the answer*, you have two completely independent operations.  The first is: *ask a question, then forget about it*.  The second is: *get an answer, then, knowing* nothing *about the question, use the answer*.  It's a completely different approach, and you need to get your head around it before using it.

(One possible further advantage of this approach is that MySQL end can now send data without being prompted.  You have the option of feeding changes made by another user to your user in real time.)

**Solution 2:**

My other solution is simpler in some ways, but it can have you firing off lots of threads.  Just have your *getSomething* method block until it has the answer and returns.  To keep your program from hanging, just put the whole block of code that calls the method in its own thread.

**Hybrid:**

You can use both solutions together.  The first one makes for cleaner code, but the second lets you answer a specific question when you get the reply.  (If you get a "Customer Name" from the DB, and you have a dozen fields it could go in, it might help to know that you did ask for this field specifically, *and* that you asked because the user pushed a button to put the value in a specific text box on the screen.)

**Lastly:**

You can avoid a lot of multithreading headaches by using InvokeLater to put all changes to your data structures on your EventQueue.  This can nicely limit the synchronization problems.  (On the other hand, having 20 or 30 threads going at once can make good use of all your computer's cores, if you like to live dangerously.)

You may want to stick with synchronized calls, but if you do want to go asynchronous, this is how I'd do it.  It's not too bad once you get some basic tools written and get your brain to stop thinking synchronously.